# Invoking google search button

Tags: c#, .net

My application has one button one text box and a webbrowser control which is going to `navigate` at `google.com` at form load event.

If I am setting the text attributes to the `google textbox` in `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` method after clicking the button I am able to invoke google search button.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=u6PkV4X9LovZ8Aec7bI4&gws_rd=ssl");
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted); 
}
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textElement = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
    textElement.SetAttribute("value", "facebook");
}
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ele = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnK")[0];
    ele.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

If I am setting the text attributes to the `google textbox` in  `btnLogin_Click` method after clicking the button i am not able to invoke google search button.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=u6PkV4X9LovZ8Aec7bI4&gws_rd=ssl");
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);   

}
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textElement = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")[0];
}
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textElement.SetAttribute("value", "facebook");
    ele = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnK")[0];
    ele.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

Where I am going wrong please suggest me.